# How to create summary table of unique value counts?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I've scoured many, many other SO posts for an answer to this question, but haven't found quite what I'm looking for. Here goes:

Let's say we have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
In [7]: df.head(5)
Out[7]:
  bool_flag   group  int_flag
0     False  bottom         0
1     False     mid         1
2     False     top         1
3     False     top         0
4     False    high         1
```

Where there are five unique groups, two unique boolean values, and two unique integer values. I'd like to create a summary table like this:

```
                 bottom   low  mid  high  top
bool_flag  true       5     32   2    12    4
          false       2     42   7     2   10
int_flag      0       1     10  15     3    8 
              1      10     31  14     0    1
```

summarizing the unique value counts of each of the non-`group` columns, and grouped in columns of `group`.

I've gotten close. The following `pivot_table` command get me tables that resemble components of what I'd like to have.

```
In [8]: pd.pivot_table(df.drop('bool_flag', axis=1), columns=['group'], index=['int_flag'], aggfunc=len)
Out[8]:
group     bottom  high  low  mid  top
int_flag
0             15    11    8   13   13
1             12     5    8    9    6


In [9]: pd.pivot_table(df.drop('int_flag', axis=1), columns=['group'], index=['bool_flag'], aggfunc=len)
Out[9]:
group      bottom  high  low  mid  top
bool_flag
False          19    14   15   18   16
True            8     2    1    4    3
```

However, the `index` of the resulting table isn't the `Multiindex` I'd like to have, and thus makes concatenating that pivot table with the same for the `bool_flag` more difficult.

I would hope that there's a way to either use `groupby` or `pivot_table` to get what I want without generating these sub-tabulations and concatenating them, but so far I haven't been able to find it. Pivoting with multiple index columns results in too fine-grained a table (I don't want the count of `(False, 0)` pairs for `(bool_flag, int_flag)` values, for example, just the count of each unique value within each `group`.)

I also attempted to use `groupby('group').agg(f)`, where I defined `f` to yield the result of calling `value_counts()` on each series. However, `agg` isn't compatible with functions that return `DataFrame`s.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Someone had asked if `df.groupby(['bool_flag','group','int_flag']).size().unstack(1)` would work, but deleted their comment. Unfortunately this doesn't work — notice that the values there aren't the ones I generated with the pivot table examples. I mentioned that I did not want the counts to represent unique value _pairs_. Instead, I just need the cross-tab of `group` vs. `bool_flag` and `group` vs. `int_flag` stacked atop one another.

Comment: I'm not going to edit it myself, but I think a more accurate title for the question might be "how to concat/append two pivot tables with different indices" or something like that -- although that particular title might not be much of an improvement.  ;-)  The hardest issue here IMO really has to do with the concat/append of indices that don't line up, moreso than making a single pivot table.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I don't think that what I'm asking for is possible. Setting the indices of the two pivot tables I showed above to `MultiIndex`s by doing the following:

```
x = pd.pivot_table(df.drop('int_flag', axis=1), columns=['group'], index=['bool_flag'], aggfunc=len)
y = pd.pivot_table(df.drop('bool_flag', axis=1), columns=['group'], index=['int_flag'], aggfunc=len)

def multiindex_from_pivot_result(df):
    return pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(df.index.name, val) for val in df.index], names=['feature', 'values'])

xx = x.set_index(multiindex_from_pivot_result(x))
yy = y.set_index(multiindex_from_pivot_result(y))
```

results in a tables that look like this:

```
group             bottom  high  low  mid  top
feature   values
bool_flag False       19    14   15   18   16
          True         8     2    1    4    3
```

and

```
group            bottom  high  low  mid  top
feature  values
int_flag 0           15    11    8   13   13
         1           12     5    8    9    6
```

however, concatenating them like so

```
pd.concat([yy, xx])
```

yields a table with the values I want, but whose index's second-level is overridden with the first frame's index values.

```
In [24]: pd.concat([yy, xx])
Out[24]:
group             bottom  high  low  mid  top
feature   values
int_flag  0           15    11    8   13   13
          1           12     5    8    9    6
bool_flag 0           19    14   15   18   16
          1            8     2    1    4    3
```

Unfortunately, that leaves me with the choice of resetting that level of the index to a normal column, which doesn't print as nicely.

Hope this helped somebody!